# Use nfs version 3 on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, nfs4

I tested using nfs version 3 on my lab system, and it works fine.

```
[root@server2 ~]# tail -1 /etc/mtab

server1:/nfs /nfs nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.150.134,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.150.134 0 0

[root@server2 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
[root@server2 ~]#
```

However. when I do the same thing on Azure, it fails. I followed this guide

[Link to vers 3 nfs](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/flame-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-change-NFS-and-AutoFS-versions-from-Version-4-to-Version-3-in-Flame.html)

But when I mount it using version 3, it gives below error

```
mount -vv  -t nfs -o vers=3 server1:/appl /wbr

mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Aug  1 02:38:02 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,addr=10.200.254.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.200.254.8 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.200.254.8 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
```

Version 4 works just fine, but version 3 does not!

Any ideas?

Comment: Stop using version 3, of course. It was obsolete almost 20 years ago.

Comment: i know, but MUST use it for our legacy app which works best on version 3

Comment: Does `showmount -e <server>`  work? Are the necessary ports op in the firewalls between the systems (portmapper and whatever ports are used for the nfs services) ?

Comment: i can mount it using version 4, that means ports are open and does not look like firewall, i have disabled both firewalld/iptables

Comment: Did you check your Azure security group?

Comment: @Michael yeah, since version 4 works fine on 111,2049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

I put this in the /etc/sysconfig/nfs file

RQUOTAD_PORT=875

LOCKD_TCPPORT=32803

LOCKD_UDPPORT=32769

MOUNTD_PORT=892

STATD_PORT=662

Then

systemctl restart nfs-config

Then I opened the above ports tcp/udp on azure and was able to mount it!

Thanks to everyone for their support!

Answer (score 0):

The vendor provides NFSv3 support in RHEL7 (see [Introduction to NFS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-nfs)).

Please do the following checks:

1) Ensure NFSv3 support is enabled in the `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` file:

```
NFS3_SERVER_SUPPORT="yes"
```

To prevent clients from using NFSv4, add the setting

```
RPCNFSDARGS= -N 4
```

2) Check if NFS daemons are running on the NFS server:

```
# service nfs status
# service portmap status
```

3) Check if your NFS server in Azure is available from the client system via NFS network ports:

- port 111 (TCP and UDP);
- port 2049 (TCP and UDP)

with any tool you prefer, e.g.:

```
# telnet nfs_server_ip_addr 2049
# nmap -sU -p 111,2049 nfs_server_ip_addr
# nmap -sT -p 111,2049 nfs_server_ip_addr
```

4) Check if existing mounts are visible from the client system:

```
# showmount -e nfs_server_name
```

Comment: 1,2) nfs is working on version 4, so everything is in place, I can telnet, nmap gives below output

PORT     STATE         SERVICE
111/udp  open          rpcbind
2049/udp open|filtered nfs

3)showmount does not show anything, but still can mount using version 4

Comment: Is NFS3 support enabled in the `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` file?  `NFS3_SERVER_SUPPORT="yes"`